# Intuition about absolute Continuity/Singularity of measures

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $\mu$, $\nu$ be two measures, $X= d\nu/d\mu$ their Radon-Nikodym derivative (in general a random variable). I want to gain an intuition about the following statements:

$$\int X\; d\mu = 1 \Leftrightarrow \nu << \mu \Leftrightarrow X < \infty, \nu-a.s.$$
and
$$X=0, \mu-a.s. \Leftrightarrow \nu \perp \mu \Leftrightarrow X = \infty, \nu-a.s.$$

Can someone explain to me what absolute continuity/singularity implies for their Radon-Nikodym derivative?

Comment: On the first eqn, $X < \infty$ $\nu$-a.e. means $nu$ has no atom contained in a set with positive $\mu$ measure, i.e. $\nu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$. Similarly, if $\int X d \mu < \int d \nu$, then $\nu$ must have an atom on a set with positive $\mu$ measure. Same reasoning applies to your second set of implications.